# how to scroll a image horizontally right to left and left to right

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to scroll a  image from left to right and right to left. Means when image did finish scroll left to right then automatically right to left scrolling is enable and then repeat it.

Like in this image. Any idea or any suggestion or sample code will be appreciate.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any code?  It should be pretty simple with a UIImageView in your scrollview and a timer.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you explain or share any demo code. I used uiscrollview many time with timer, where i use paging with many image. I dont know how todo it with a single image. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: It is the same as with many images except you just have one large image and you will need to move the content offset a little each time your timer ticks.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have to try it, if you share any  demo or code its little bit easy to work. by the way thanks alot

Comment: @Paulw11 can you suggest me the right content offset .. its quit typical for me to calulate .

Comment: It would vary from x=0 to x=imageWidth-scrollviewWidth I imagine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an `NSTimer`, you should use `UIView animate` function.

I just tried with the following code
In `viewDidLoad`

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.scrollView addSubview:imageV];
```

and in the `viewDidAppear`

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(imageV.frame.size.width - self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0);
}];
```

Comment: how to implement it and where to implement this function , can you explain it more. please

Comment: It really depends where this function should be implemented. I've tried it with `viewDidAppear` function of `UIViewController`

Comment: or any other change in that i have to do in scrollview properties and methods. and what size is set to be as scrollView contentSize ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try it.

Comment: and please now tell me how to scroll it reverse ?

Comment: Use this `self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);`, in the UIView animate function.

Comment: after adding this line uiview stop animating

Comment: this animation is performing scrolling from right to left ...that great but after completion of it it should be reverse scroll left to right ... that i want how can I achive it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89887/discussion-between-shamas-s-and-subhash-sharma).